# How to get specific string with batch for loop when it is in a line below a string we search?

Tags: batch, findstr

I have an issue I am not sure how to deal with. I need to search a txt file where the search string is on the top but the actual data needed is in the next line underneath.

Example:
So I just noticed that not all of my question was showing, under the example is an actual example.

```
{<  Setting name= "SerialNumber" serializeAs= "String" >}

{< Value > I-Need-This-Data < /value >}
```

I already have created the script, I just need help creating the FOR command so I can Set variable to the data I need to use within the script.

```
For /f "delim?/token" %%a in (findstr "Serial Number" d:\...\text.txt ) do set SN=%%a
```

I am not sure about the token or delim. How would I type out the "for" to get it to look at the second line after it finds the serial number?

Comment: Parsing a file with batch that contains greater-than and less-than chars is going to hurt.  Findstr can do it without breaking but the second that line gets into your batch file, it will break the bank.  I would suggest moving this problem to Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

- Batch file:

```bat
for /f tokens^=3delims^=^<^/^> %%i in ('type file.txt ^| findstr /i "Value"')do set "_sn=%%~i"
```

- Command line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=3delims^=^<^/^> %i in ('type file.txt ^| findstr /i "Value"')do set "_sn=%~i"
```

---

```bat
>for /f tokens^=3delims^=^<^/^> %i in ('type file.txt ^| findstr /i "Value"')do set "_sn=%~i"

>set "_sn= I-Need-This-Data "
```

---

**Obs.:** To extract the string by removing the before and after spaces, use the <kbd>**SPACE**</kbd> as the delimiter:

```bat
< Value > I-Need-This-Data < /value >
```

Use multiple delimiters including space:

```bat
for /f tokens^=3delims^=^<^/^>^SPACE %i

>for /f tokens^=3delims^=^<^/^>^  %i in ('type file.txt ^| findstr /i "Value"')do set "_sn=%~i"

>set "_sn=I-Need-This-Data"
```